# Parallel processing using "parallel" in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-markdown

I have data table that I am uploading in R (.csv format with multiple columns) on which certain user-defined rules need to be applied (another file in .csv format, where each row defines a rule).

Currently I am using a for loop to iterate through the dataset and apply these rules (thus making them sequential). However, the output of each of these rules is independent and, thus, I want to ensure they run in parallel.

I explored the **parallel** package in R but couldn't narrow down on what I'm looking for. What I'm looking for is -

**dataset** is my data table
**rulesSet** is my rules file

*^ These are being read in an .Rmd file*

**applyRules(dataset,rulesSet)** is the function which takes the above two as parameters and returns a resultant data

*^This function is present in a separate util.R file but is being called from the .Rmd*

Each row of rulesSet to apply to dataset and return the resultant data table. I tried writing -

```
clusterApplyLB(cl=clust,
               sampleRules,
               fun=function(x){
                   applyRules(sampleDataset, x, "union")
               })
```

and also parLapply/Sapply using the same format but in vain (I get an error saying **could not find function applyRules**)

Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What is `"union"` doing in your call to `applyRules()`? I assume it is a parameter that you don't mention above.

Comment: It's nothing but how i want the outputs of each rule to interact with each other, i.e. if "union" then union the output datasets, if "intersection" then likewise

Comment: Did either of these answers solve your problem? If so, you should accept one of them by clicking the green checkbox under the voting buttons. If not, let us know what's wrong so we can update or refine our answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a cluster using `parallel` or `snow` it generates a number of nodes which are actually separate `rsession` instances (you can check this by looking in Activity Monitor, Task Manager, or top while they're running). Since they're separate R Sessions, they each have their own environment and cannot see objects loaded in your main R environment. You need to use the `clusterExport` function to export any objects that the nodes need to work with into their environment before you run `clusterApply`.

Now, in your case, this result is strange because you *can* pass in objects and functions through the `clusterApplyLB` function. However, the error you're getting tells me that, for whatever reason, one of your nodes is trying to call `applyRules` from an environment where it's not available. Try exporting your function (and possibly your datasets as well, if necessary) to the cluster as below and see if that solves your problem.

```
cl <- makecluster(4)
clusterExport(cl, 'applyRules')
results <- clusterApplyLB(cl,
                          sampleRules,
                          fun = function(x) {
                              applyRules(sampleDataset, x, "union")
                          })
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Good explanation but OP is likely going to have to export more than the applyRules function

Answer (score 1):

Author of the [future](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) framework here.  If you can get the following, sequential call, to work:

```
res <- lapply(sampleRules, FUN = function(x) {
  applyRules(sampleDataset, x, "union")
})
```

then you might have better success with:

```
library(future.apply)
plan(multiprocess)

res <- future_lapply(sampleRules, FUN = function(x) {
  applyRules(sampleDataset, x, "union")
})
```

because it tries to identify all dependent packages and global objects and automatically export them to the workers.